importing Jupyter notebook into another notebook as a module
I am trying to import one Jupyter notebook into another notebook as a module, I have a file name My_Module.ipynb and trying to import it to a file named Import_Module.ipynb by using:
import import_ipynb 
 import My_Module

But throwing an error: NameError: name 'null' is not defined
I tried:
import import_ipynb 
 import My_Module

I wad expecting to import My_Module as a module and use functions defined in it

This answer to 'Package for Importing Jupyter Notebooks as Modules' covers this. Also see 'How to import jupyter notebook to another jupyter notebook?' and 'import in jupyter notebook to use a method from another file' are just a few of the recent exchanges covering this topic.

 Please for next time read How do I ask a good question? and follow it. Note immediately after stressing that your questions is on-topic and suitable it emphasizes 'Search, and Research'. Cite what resources you have looked into and how they didn't address the issue, if that is the case. Jupyter happens to have a Python kernel among many other languages. Python should at least be mentioned in the post or a topic tag. Knowing the underlying language involved is important to understanding how to search for help.

I should add 'How can I import from another ipython-notebook?' is the older post about this from back when Jupyter was just the IPython notebook project, and I have an example there spelled out.

Hi @Wayne, thanks for the solution and the advice. It worked.
As I am new to stack overflow as well as programming so would keep in mind your suggestions from the next time.
Thanks

Glad it worked out. Welcome to SO and hope my tips make your experience better.
